# Python Tkinter: How to fix image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas, python-3.9

I have been working on a school project but for some reason the error "image "pyimage1" doesn't exist" exist during debugging. The error message pops up on the "logo_label = Label(logo_frame, image=logo_image, bg='#000000')" line. Below is the code that is related:

```
 # Logo Image Resize
    logo_path = "AnisaLogo.png"
    InLogoImage = Image.open(r'C:\Users\User\source\repos\PythonApplication1\AnisaLogo.png')
    resized_logo = InLogoImage.resize((359, 150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    logo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_logo)

    # Logo Image Frame
    logo_frame = Frame(center_frame)
    logo_frame.config(bg='#000000')
    logo_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

    # Print Logo image
    logo_label = Label(logo_frame, image=logo_image, bg='#000000')
    logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Below is the full code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import ast
import Anisa_Home

def Registration():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('900x400')
    root.title("Anisa - Registration And Sign In")
    root.config(bg='#FFEBCE')

    def PWCheck():
        errors = []

        if password_entry.get() != c_password_entry.get():
            errors.append("Passwords don't match!")

        if len(password_entry.get()) < 8:
            errors.append("Password length must be at least 8 characters!")

        if not any(char.isdigit() for char in password_entry.get()):
            errors.append("Your password must contain at least one numerical alphabet!")

        if not any(char.isalpha() for char in password_entry.get()):
            errors.append("Your password must contain at least one English alphabet!")

        if errors:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "\n".join(errors))
            return False

        return True

    def Register():
        if email_entry.get() == "":
            messagebox.showinfo("Register", "Please input Email!")
        else:
            try:
                file = open('datasheet.txt', 'r')
                d = file.read()
                r = ast.literal_eval(d)
                file.close()
                if email_entry.get() in r:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Register", "Email exists!")
                else:
                    if PWCheck():
                        r[email_entry.get()] = password_entry.get()
                        file = open('datasheet.txt', 'w')
                        file.write(str(r))
                        file.close()
                        messagebox.showinfo("Register", "Register successful!")
                        
            except:
                if PWCheck():
                    d = {email_entry.get(): password_entry.get()}
                    file = open('datasheet.txt', 'w')
                    file.write(str(d))
                    file.close()
                    messagebox.showinfo("Register", "Register successful!")

    def Login():
        email_get = email_entry.get()
        password_get = password_entry.get()

        file = open('datasheet.txt', 'r')
        d = file.read()
        r = ast.literal_eval(d)
        file.close()
        if email_get in r and r[email_get] == password_get:
            messagebox.showinfo("Login", "Login successful!")
            toggle_home()
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Login", "Invalid email or password!")

    def show_password():
        if password_entry.cget('show') == '':
            password_entry.config(show='*')
            c_password_entry.config(show='*')
        else:
            password_entry.config(show='')
            c_password_entry.config(show='')

    center_frame = Frame(root)
    center_frame.config(pady=60, bg='#000000')
    center_frame.pack(anchor='center', expand=True)

    # Logo Image Resize
    logo_path = "AnisaLogo.png"
    InLogoImage = Image.open(r'C:\Users\User\source\repos\PythonApplication1\AnisaLogo.png')
    resized_logo = InLogoImage.resize((359, 150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    logo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_logo)

    # Logo Image Frame
    logo_frame = Frame(center_frame)
    logo_frame.config(bg='#000000')
    logo_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

    # Print Logo image
    logo_label = Label(logo_frame, image=logo_image, bg='#000000')
    logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # Register frame
    register_frame = Frame(center_frame)
    register_frame.config(bg='#000000')
    register_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="NSEW")

    # Button frame
    button_frame = Frame(center_frame)
    button_frame.config(bg='#000000')
    button_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="NSEW")

    sep_line = Label(register_frame, text="--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
                    bg='#000000', fg='white')
    sep_line.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='ew')

    sep_line_2 = Label(register_frame, text="--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
                    bg='#000000', fg='white')
    sep_line_2.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='ew')

    # username label and text entry box
    email_label = Label(register_frame, text="Email", bg='#000000', fg='white')
    email_label.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, sticky='w')
    email = StringVar()
    email_entry = Entry(register_frame, textvariable=email, width=30)
    email_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)

    # password label and password entry box
    password_label = Label(register_frame, text="Password", bg='#000000', fg='white')
    password_label.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5, sticky='w')
    password = StringVar()
    password_entry = Entry(register_frame, textvariable=password, show='*', width=30)
    password_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)

    # Confirm Password label and entry box
    c_password_label = Label(register_frame, text="Confirm Password", bg='#000000', fg='white')
    c_password_label.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=5, sticky='w')
    c_password = StringVar()
    c_password_entry = Entry(register_frame, textvariable=c_password, show='*', width=30)
    c_password_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)

    # Show Password button
    show_password_button = Button(button_frame, text="Show Password", width=19, command=show_password)
    show_password_button.grid(row=5, column=2, pady=10, padx=5, sticky='e')

    # Register button
    btn_register = Button(button_frame, text="Register", width=19, command=Register)
    btn_register.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=10, padx=5, sticky='e')

    # Login button
    btn_login = Button(button_frame, text="Login", width=19, command=Login)
    btn_login.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=10, padx=5, sticky='e')

    # Close the window
    def on_closing():
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
            root.destroy()

    def toggle_home():
        root.destroy()
        Anisa_Home

    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
    root.mainloop()

# Entry Point
Registration()
```

I have tried to put the image resize part outside of the root.mainloop() according to chatgpt but it did not work. The error message "local variable 'logo_image' referenced before assignment" popped up after I did that. Also, I have made sure the path and the photo format is correct. May I ask why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please try to reduce the size of the example down to a [mcve]. If the question is about an image, we only need enough widgets to show the image, and we don't need all the functions that aren't necessary to show the image.

Comment: Most probably it is caused by using multiple instances of `Tk()`.